# Where is the withPipeline function in MongoDB Spark connector

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, pipeline, connector

I am trying to load some data from MongoDB into Spark. I have defined a ReadConfig to specify the database and collection. I want also to apply a filter, to avoid loding all the collection. I am following the example from https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/aggregation/
 as:

val rc = ReadConfig(Map("database" -> "myDB", "collection" -> "myCol"), Some(ReadConfig(spark)))

val rdd = MongoSpark.load(spark,rc)

but rdd does not have any function named withPipeline ( seems that it generated a regualr DataFrame not a MongoRDD) 
Do I miss to import something?
I already have imported

import com.mongodb.spark._

import spark.implicits._

Comment: Which version of MongoDB Spark connector are you using ? Could you share how you are loading the jar dependencies for the connector as well ? i.e. `spark-shell --packages ...`

Comment: I am using version  2.10 of the mongodb connector for Spakr version 2.x, given in the build.sbt file (libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.10" % "2.0.0") . Then I import com.mongodb.spark._

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using spark 2.0
Use `Spark.sparkContext` while using `MongoSpark.load`

```
val collectionDf = MongoSpark.load(spark.sparkContext, readConfig)
val aggregatedRdd = collectionDf.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("{ $match: { _id: 'value' } }")))
```